# Pygame not detecting the a key when ctrl and shift are pressed

Tags: python, pygame

I have a issue where pygame does not detect the a key getting pressed when I press ctrl, shift and a simultaneously. which is a problem in my game.

is there any solution or work-around for this problem? I pasted some example code below to show how I detect key input. I looked around but couldn't find any solution.

ps: it's not my keyboards fault it has a 10 key rollover and ctrl + shift + d works fine so it must be something else

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
while True:
   pygame.event.get()
   events = pygame.key.get_pressed()


   if events[pygame.K_a]:
       
       #do something

   if events[pygame.K_d]:
       
       #do something

   pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: it shouldn't be, my keyboard can detect 14 keys pressed at once and other keykombinations work fine

Comment: Windows 10 latest version

Comment: and pygame 2.0.0

Comment: The problem is not with your code, but with your system. I cannot reproduce the issue. WIndows 10, Python 3.9.0, Pygame 2.0.1

Comment: I did the key rollover test and it seems so that my keyboard detects 10 - 14 keys with ctrl and shift but not a.... only a? what. issue solver for now I guess